# Trying to grab league statistics in order to compute win rates for inhouse games

Tags: http, deno, riot-games-api

I have been trying to use the riot games api to compute all the previous custom games and then find the win loss streaks for individual players, I have built the following code to grab matches for a particular user.

See https://github.com/FriendlyUser/deno-riot-games-custom-games

But I feel like the riot games api is only returning data with its v4 api up to season 11, if anyone could clarify how the api works or explain how I could possibly get more data, that would be fantastic.

```
import { writeJson } from "https://deno.land/std/fs/mod.ts"
import "https://deno.land/x/dotenv/load.ts"

const player_id = Deno.env.get('ACCOUNT_ID')
const region_url = 'https://na1.api.riotgames.com'
let riot_URL = new URL(`${region_url}/lol/match/v4/matchlists/by-account/${player_id}`)

enum HTTP {
  GET = 'GET',
  POST = 'POST',
  PUT = 'PUT',
  DELETE = 'DELETE'
}

interface MatchlistDto {
  startIndex: number
  totalGames: number
  endIndex: number
  matches: Array<any>
}

function makeFetchOptions(
    riotKey = Deno.env.get('RIOT_API_KEY'),
    method: HTTP = HTTP.GET
): object {
  return {
      method: method,
      headers: { 
        "Accept-Charset": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        "Accept-Language":  "en-US,en;q=0.9",
        'X-Riot-Token': riotKey
      }
  }
}

function appendMatchHistory(riot_endpoint: string): Promise<MatchlistDto> {
  const riotKey = Deno.env.get('RIOT_API_KEY')
  console.log(riotKey)
  const options = makeFetchOptions(riotKey)
  return fetch(riot_endpoint, options)
  .then( (resp: any) => {
    console.log(resp)
    return resp.json() 
  })
  .then( (matchData: MatchlistDto) => {
    return matchData
  })
}

const max_iterations = 1000
let bIndex = 0
let eIndex = 100
let current_url = riot_URL
let riot_endpoint = null
let allMatches = []
let customGames = []

const sleep = (milliseconds: number) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds))
}

for (let i = 0; i < max_iterations; i++) {
    console.log(`beginIndex: ${bIndex} endIndex: ${eIndex}`)
    riot_endpoint = current_url.toString()
    const newMatches = await appendMatchHistory(riot_endpoint)
    await sleep(1500)
    current_url.searchParams.delete('beginIndex')
    current_url.searchParams.delete('endIndex')
    const {matches} = newMatches
    if (matches.length == 0) {
      console.log(`ENDING SCRIPT AT ${eIndex} with ${matches.length}`)
      break
    }
    // startIndex becomes endIndex
    bIndex = eIndex
    eIndex = eIndex + 100
    allMatches.push(newMatches.matches)

    // get new url
    current_url.searchParams.append('beginIndex', String(bIndex))
    current_url.searchParams.append('endIndex', String(eIndex))
}

await writeJson(
  "./allData.json",
  allMatches
);
```

Comment: Should I just assume the league api doesn't provide data before season 11 kinda like how they got rid of the league forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if this answer is late. But yes the Riot API is only for "current" data, and that is why sites like U.GG, OP.GG, etc actually run scripts to store data continuously. So to get statistics you would have to write scripts to store it into your own DB over time.

**Sadly, there is no way to get previous season data**